# How does the Anglerfish being blind help me avoid them?

Tags: outer-wilds

I'm playing outer wilds, and trying to solve it all myself, so I'm not asking how to avoid the anglerfish.  I have discovered anglerfish cave on ember twin, and learned that anglerfish are blind, and read all of the writing in the cave (I think).  I have gone to Dark Bramble many times, and visited many locations (including feldspars camp).  The problem is, that I now need to go into the place with all the anglerfish. (I have found out that I can't enter dark bramble in my ship). i have gotten past them before, but I can't find any reason to how I do it, and now I get eaten all the time.  Here's my question:  Have I discovered all the writing that is going to help me get past them?  Is the fact that they are blind my only clue?  I'm trying not to ruin the fun of discovery, but I'm trying to figure out whether the anglerfish are finicky or I haven't read something.  thnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the anglerfish are blind, they cannot see you, but they can hear you, especially your suit and ship thrusters. This means that you need to go through Dark Bramble very quietly. Your suit and ship thrusters will alert them above very minimal thrust, but it can be tricky to regulate the exact thruster output allowed. The more consistent method is to not use thrust at all while a fish is in the room.

Gain as much speed as possible before entering the anglerfish room and then cut off all input (I usually set my controller on the table while floating by just in case). Wait until you are well past them before making any other jetpack inputs. You maintain momentum pretty well in space, so you should be able to make it to the other side of the room with only an initial boost at the beginning.

This video demonstrates the technique in action:

Comment: You can actually use extremely minimal thrust with the ship and still not alert the fish.  it needs to be so minimal that it does not register on your gauge.

Comment: @GnomeSlice I think that's part of what can make it feel inconsistent though; it's much more consistent to just float through with your hands off the controller

Comment: "Gain as much speed as possible before entering the anglerfish room" -  the speed with which you enter a node is irrelevant; your speed (and trajectory) after you enter a node will always be the same, a slow drift directly forward.